# Android desaturate specific color

Tags: android, colors, bitmap, image-effects

I am making some kind of image filter, and I need to *desaturate* (remove saturation) for a specific color. For example red. I want my image to replace all red colors with gray.
Change this image
[image]

To this
[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It's say there http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrixColorFilter.html that ColorMatrixColorFilter can be used to change saturation of pixel. But you have to play with math and [ColorMatrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrix.html)

Is that what you're researching ?

Edit :
There is not such thing in Android standard library. Filter are written in NDK for performance issue, so you'll need to do the same for a custom filter.

Another idea without thinking of performance is : loop through all pixels and desaturate when it's "red"

Comment: I didn't use ColorMatrixColorFilter until now. Is there a way to remove spectre of specific colour? Like in image I have posted up.
I don't want to remove only #ff0000, but all red colors.

Comment: I suppose red color = A color with R>0 in RGB value ?

Comment: Yeah, but (219, 148, 36) is orange, not red.

Comment: Well, how do you define red ?

Comment: Well, that is the problem. That image from above is photoshop effect. I have desaturated red color. I need same effect for android. If there is one.

Comment: It seems, ColorMatrixColorFilter is not your solution... I will think of something else

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use OR login to add a "filter" to your color RGB or ARGB

```
int filter = 0x00CC0000 | color;
myView.setBackgroundColor(filter);
```